# DBCP Close all opened connections

Tags: java, database, apache-commons-dbcp, mssql-jdbc

I am using dbcp connection pooling and having long running stored procedures. There are several connections opened and database (mssql) server machine gets powered off, which leaves these connections opened. How can I get list of opened connections from pooling and close them manually from my java web application?

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Object obj = initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/oscon");
            BasicDataSource source = (BasicDataSource) obj;
```

I am using commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close them manually. The best thing to do is just configure [Connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing), in which case c3p0 will silently (but lazily) close the old Connections and acquire new ones.

If you want to be more proactive than that, just call [hardReset()](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html#hardReset--) on the c3p0 data source (after casting it to [PooldedDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html).

Comment: Whats the way to cast BasicDataSource to PooledDataSource ?

Comment: InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
   Object obj = initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/oscon");
   BasicDataSource source = (BasicDataSource) obj;
   PooledDataSource pds = (PooledDataSource) DataSources.pooledDataSource(source);
   pds.hardReset();

Comment: c3p0 doesn't offer a BasicDataSource. after your lookup, try `PooledDataSource pds = (PooledDataSource) obj;` directly. then hard reset, as you've done.

Comment: Nothing you are doing should create a new DataSource or pool of Connections (unless the first one hasn't been initialized). The lookup will find an existing instance of the DataSource, if it exists in your JVM and ClassLoader. You are not using the DataSources factory class to create a new instance, those docs are irrelevant. Your instance is coming from JNLP, however you've configured that and set it up.

Comment: Sorry its dbcp not c3p0. I changed main description. Can you please give me solution for the same?

Comment: (sorry! i don't know dbcp well enough.)